# C++ More than one instance of constructor tiny question

Tags: c++

```
class Money
{

    long int cents = 0;
public:
    int get_cents () const { return cents; }
    Money operator+(const Money& m);
    Money(long m) : cents{m} {}
    Money(double m);

};

Money Money::operator+(const Money& m)
{
    //5.72+7.32
    //1500/100
    cout << (cents + m.cents);
    return Money(1500);
    //return Money(1500)
}
```

When I have a constructor that takes a long argument this doesn't work and throws an error but when I replace that long with an int this works just fine. Why is that?

Comment: `Money(double m);` why is this constructor required?

Comment: Ambiguity between `int`->`long` or `int`->`double`...

Comment: Note that your operator overload should really be a `const` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
return Money(1500);
```

According to the rules of C++, `1500` is an `int`.

The same rules of C++ allow an `int` to be converted to either `long` or `double`, without any explicit preference of one over the other. Unfortunately, your C++ compiler can't really flip a coin in the air and choose which constructor to call based on the results of a coin toss. Hence the compilation error.

Comment: Okay but how come it doesn't give me an error if I use an int instead of a long? Isn't a long just an int but with 64 bits?

Comment: It is a bit funny that C++ does not prefer the conversion to `long` which is always possible without loss of precision. The same is not necessarily true for the conversion to `double`.

Comment: @yaelreshet11 If you use `int` there is no conversion needed since 1500 is already an `int`.

Comment: @nielsen Rules of the language in this case have nothing to do with whether any of the conversions lose value.  The rule is simply that a match involving no implicit conversion is better than a match involving one implicit conversion. Conversion of `int` to `double` or conversion of `int` to `long` are therefore equally viable options, hence the ambiguity. Incidentally, the same ambiguity would occur with two constructors, one accepting a `long` and another accepting a `long long`.  A literal of type `int` can be converted to either `long` or `long long` without losing information.

Comment: @Peter: Funny you should say that, but an `int` to a `long` will never (well perhaps it can, see later) lose value, but an `int` to a `double` might. Granted not if you have a 32 bit `int` and an IEEE754 `double`, but if you have a 64 bit `int` then things are different. That said I wonder if the complementing scheme can be different if an `int` and a `long` are the same size - it could then be lossy if `long` has a signed zero type. But even that corner case goes away with C++20.